# How to dynamically allocate memory without affecting other data allocated dynamically?

Tags: c

Im implementing a card game using C, here's my code:

## deck.h:

```
#ifndef DECK_H
    #define DECK_H
    #define S_NUM 4
    #define V_NUM 12
    #define S_MAXLEN 9
    #define V_MAXLEN 6
    #define OFLEN 5

    typedef char deck_t
        [S_NUM * V_NUM]
            [S_MAXLEN + V_MAXLEN + OFLEN];
    
    typedef struct {
        deck_t *hand;
        deck_t *remaining_cards;
    } dealed_deck_t;
    
    deck_t *new_deck(void);
    void print_deck(const deck_t *);
    dealed_deck_t deal(const deck_t *, int);
    void free_deck(const deck_t *);
    
    static void deckcpy(const deck_t *const, deck_t *, int);
    
#endif
```

## deck.c:

```
#include "deck.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

deck_t *new_deck() {
    int i, j, k;
    deck_t *cards = calloc(1, sizeof(deck_t));
    char suits[S_NUM][S_MAXLEN] = {
        "Spades", "Diamonds",
        "Hearts", "Clubs"
    };
    char values[V_NUM][V_MAXLEN] = {
        "Ace", "Two", "Three",
        "Four", "Five", "Six",
        "Seven", "Eight", "Nine",
        "Jack", "Queen", "King"
    };
    for (i = 0; i < S_NUM * V_NUM; ++i) {
        memset(*cards[i], 0, strlen(*cards[i]));
    }
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < S_NUM; ++i) {
        for (k = 0; k < V_NUM; ++k, ++j) {
            strcat(*cards[j], values[k]);
            strcat(*cards[j], " of ");
            strcat(*cards[j], suits[i]);
        }
    }
    return cards;
}

void print_deck(const deck_t *deck) {
    for (int i = 0; i < S_NUM * V_NUM && strlen(*deck[i]); ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", *deck[i]);
    }
}

dealed_deck_t deal(const deck_t *deck, int handsize) {
    int i, j;
    dealed_deck_t dealed_deck;
    dealed_deck.hand = calloc(1, sizeof(deck_t));
    dealed_deck.remaining_cards = calloc(1, sizeof(deck_t));
    
    // print_deck(deck);
    
    return dealed_deck;
}

void free_deck(const deck_t *deck) {
    free((void *)deck);
}

static void deckcpy(const deck_t *const deck, deck_t *dest, int handsize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < handsize; ++i) {
        char temp[strlen(*deck[i])];
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(*deck[i]); ++j) {
            temp[j] = (*deck[i])[j];
            temp[j] = '\0';
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(temp); ++j) {
            (*dest[i])[j] = temp[j];
            (*dest[i])[j] = '\0';
        }
    }
}
```

## main.c:

```
#include "deck.h"

int main() {
    deck_t *cards = new_deck();
    deck_t *hand = deal(cards, 6).hand;
    // print_deck(cards);
    free_deck(cards);
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is deck.c in the deal function.
when I allocate memory for `dealed_deck.hand` and `dealed_deck.remaining_cards` the data pointed to by the parameter `deck` is affected and changed, so when I comment the two lines:
`dealed_deck.hand = calloc(1, sizeof(deck_t));` and `dealed_deck.remaining_cards = calloc(1, sizeof(deck_t));`, the data is the same, when I uncomment the data change a bit.

I'm using `calloc` here because when I used malloc the data pointed to by `dealed_deck.hand` and `dealed_deck.remaining_cards` was the same as the data pointed to by `deck`,  but when I used `calloc` they were empty as I want.

I need a way to allocate memory without messing the memory and data I allocated before, how to do that?

I'm compiling using a MacOS and gcc.
thanks.

Comment: Given that `cards` is a `deck_t *`, just what do you think `cards[i]` is?  You should probably turn on **all** compiler warnings...

Comment: I have no compiler warning at all, I'm compiling like this: `gcc main.c deck.c`

Comment: and when I compile the current code with -Wall, all I get is unused variables, and an unused function

Comment: The overall approach is already totally wrong. A card shouldn't be defined as a two strings (e.g. "Ace", "Hearts") in first place. Throw that code away, think it over and start from scratch.

Comment: I accept that, but I'm really interested in the situation here, because books or instructors never mention that `malloc` or `calloc` can be such a mess, and affecting the previously allocate data (if that is really what's happening as my conclusion).

Comment: also here a card is just a string "Ace of Spades", "King of Clubs", I'm using an array of strings to represent a deck, sorry if the code is unreadable, its just a training project.

Comment: *books or instructors never mention that malloc or calloc can be such a mess*  Oh yes they do.  What you are doing is a classic buffer overflow.  It even has a Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Comment: @AndrewHenle: A buffer overflow is more typically where an index or pointer is properly used to access parts of a buffer but overruns the end (or start). This does not match that pattern; in this case, a wrong expression was used so that the index was not properly expressing an access into a buffer but was expressing an undesired construct. In other words, the problem is not that the index was too large but that the expression it was used in was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `memset(*cards[i], 0, strlen(*cards[i]));` is wrong. First, `cards` was allocated with `calloc`, so it is filled with zero bytes, which act as empty strings. So, if `*cards[i]` pointed to something in `cards`, `strlen` returns zero, and `memset` sets zero bytes to zero.

Unfortunately, `*cards[i]` is valid only when `i` is zero. Since `cards` is a pointer to a `deck_t`, `cards[0]` is the first `deck_t`, which is an array of array of `char`. As an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first, element, an array of `char`. Then `*cards[0]` is that array of `char`. As an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, which is passed to `strlen`. However, when `i` is one (or greater), `cards[i]` would be the second (or greater) `deck_t`. But space for only one `deck_t` was allocated. So `*cards[i]` is invalid; it attempts to access space that was not allocated.

Since this line is not needed (due to `calloc`), remove it and the loop it is in.

In `strcat(*cards[j]`, the same problem exists—`*cards[j]` is valid only when `j` is zero. A correct expression is `(*cards)[j]`.

In `(*cards)[j]`, `cards` is a pointer to a `deck_t`, so `(*cards)` is a `deck_t`, which is an array of array of `char`. Then `(*cards)[j]` is element `j` of that array, so it is an array of `char`.

Similarly, in `print_deck`, change `*deck[i]` to `(*deck)[i]`.

(The code can be changed so that `deck[i]` can be used instead of `(*deck)[i]` by changing the type of `deck` to `char (*MyType)[S_MAXLEN + V_MAXLEN + OFLEN]`. However, you may wish to make the above changes first and understand them before changing types.)

Comment: so you are saying, that as a pointer to a deck_t, the second index in moving as the size of a deck_t, not to the second element of the array (the second string) in it ?.

Comment: but when I use `(*card)[j]` I'm fetching the array firstly then accessing its elements